# How to "Link to alternative location (Linked Folder)" in Android Studio like in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, android-ndk, android-studio

I have Eclipse project with **jni** folder and in the jni folder I link a folder (named CDVS_evaluation_framework) with my native C++ classes.
How to do the same in Android Studio without copy all CDVS_evaluation_framework folder (under control version) ?
thanks a lot.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly IntelliJ IDEA doesn't have feature of creating links.

I think that you need to add a content root to your module. Just right-click on your application and choose "Open Module Settings" option (or press F4 on your keyboard). After that in section **Project Settings**->**Modules** Click **+ Add Content Root** and specify your JNI-stuff directory.

Other way is to modify **build.gradle** file to make it possible to find the root directory of your JNI code.

Comment: Maybe Project Structure -> Modules -> Android -> Native libs directory will be enough? It's pretty hard to find some kind of documentation which says how to configure JNI dependencies in easy way.