# Netbeans add an external folder into a project (like Linked Folder on Eclipse)

Tags: java, netbeans

How can I add an external folder into a Netbeans project? In my case I need to add an images folder from an network drive.
In Eclipse I do this by adding a Linked Folder. What is the similar procedure in Netbeans?

Currently I'm using Netbeans 8 and created a web java project (Ant).

I can do this by adding the folder content on the build ant script or by creating a symbolic link to the specific path. Both operation are time consuming... Probably there is a (hidden) easy way to do this on Netbeans. Help please

Thanks

Comment: The images folder content will be changed by the developers team (ex: add new images or delete images)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way that I found it was by creating a symbolic link...

To create a symbolic link on windows I followed this tutorial: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend simply making a `Resources` folder in the same directory as your `src` folder. Place your images in that folder, and ensure you specify the filepath accordingly when using the images in your Java project, and you should be fine. 

If in your Java project you intend on iterating over images or something like that and the images will be changing on the network drive, you can always use some kind of folder synchronization method like using a [briefcase](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/sync-using-briefcase#1TC=windows-7). Then you can create a briefcase folder for your external folder within your Netbeans directory, and use something like [*auto-scanning of resources*](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/enable_auto_scanning_of_sources) to ensure your application continues to use the updated folder. 
There may be a much simpler way but this method seems feasible IMO.

Comment: This is not possible because I need the images folder to be in a specific project location (web/assets/images). In Eclipse we can do this with adding new folder type as "Linked folder", take a look here to see some screen shots of how it works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27619197/how-to-link-to-alternative-location-linked-folder-in-android-studio-like-in

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can go to Project Properties --> Sources --> Add Folder
here you can select your folder to add..

Comment: This is not possible because I need the images folder to be in a specific project location (web/assets/images)

Answer (score 0):

I created a folder with the same name and the same path as the one I needed from the remote server, then right click and Download.